# Drawing angled lines in CSS

Tags: css, line, css-shapes

What I'm trying to do LOOKS simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

As you can see in my image there are a couple of red lines that go across the bottom, then bend upwards close to the right side.

Is there a way in CSS to draw a line like this?

[image: example showing lines]

Comment: Do you just want angled lines (or) one line above the image and one line behind like in the screenshot?

Comment: I just need to know how to draw lines like those. I can then duplicate it for the second line, and set the z-index values to get the overlap effect.

Comment: Would [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/xGGPrL) suffice?

Comment: Yes, that give me enough information. If you post it as an answer to use the skew transformation I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: Was working on exactly same idea as @Harry before I saw his edit. [Here is my example for you anyway](http://jsbin.com/vaweju/1/edit?html,css,output), can be resized infinitely :)

Comment: @misterManSam, for what I'm doing the lines would need to also used a fixed positioning. Is that possible?

Comment: @SherwinFlight - Certainly is, do you want something [like this example](http://jsbin.com/vaweju/2/edit)?

Comment: Yep, thanks misterManSam :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can create angled lines in CSS by using skew transforms (`transform: skew(Xdeg)`). Below is a sample snippet:

```css
.shape {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

Double line with one above the content area and one behind it can also be done using a single element (and a couple of pseudos) like in the below snippet:

```css
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  Some text that goes within the element...
</div>
```

Comment: @SherwinFlight: Welcome mate. I have also added a sample for getting the exact appearance as in the image (with only 1 element). One thing that has to be noted is that since we are doing a skew, the slanted border would be a little thin but that can be overcome by making that border thicker than the other.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to "cut off" the top left corner of a DIV? For example, so that it looks like a piece of paper with the top left corner folded back, or removed.

Comment: Is the background a solid color? If yes, you could use a triangle and place it at the top. If not, it still can be achieved but would need some extra work.

Comment: No, the background is not a solid colour. :(

Comment: Then you could use `linear-gradient` like in [this pen](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/xGGPrL?editors=010). It uses a transparent gradient for the top 20px and then the actual background required for the content for the rest. This would work even if the page background is an image or another gradient.

Comment: Was working on exactly same idea as @Harry before I saw his edit. [Here is my example for you anyway](http://jsbin.com/vaweju/1/edit?html,css,output), can be resized infinitely :)

Comment: In your top example css what is causing the line to only angle at the end as apposed from the start which is what I need?