# create slanted border with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want create a line with slanted border like this http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=0ea293a (red line)

how make this with css-css3 or js ?

```
<div id="DIV_1">
    <img src="/uploads/2016/01/logo.jpg" width="250px" id="IMG_2" alt='' />
    <nav id="NAV_3">

        <button id="BUTTON_4">
            Primary Menu
        </button>
        <div id="DIV_5">
            <ul id="UL_6">
                <li id="LI_7">
                    <a href="/lcvb/" id="A_8">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="LI_9">
                    <a href="#" id="A_10">about</a>
                </li>
                <li id="LI_11">
                    <a href="#" id="A_12">location</a>
                </li>
                <li id="LI_13">
                    <a href="#" id="A_14">service & quality</a>
                </li>
                <li id="LI_15">
                    <a href="#" id="A_16">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Only some tipps: use `:before` and/or `:after` pseudo elements, `border`s and `transform: rotate()`.

Comment: @Linus Caldwell , can you show me a example, i don't understand

Comment: @SURTLER77: I see only a slanted border and not a curve. Is that what you meant by curve? If yes have a look at this one -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982414/drawing-angled-lines-in-css/29982491#29982491

Comment: @Harry yes sorry, i want a slanted border

Comment: Or even this should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705653/creating-a-css-double-border-line-with-a-step-in-the-middle/32709102#32709102 and this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917180/creating-a-tab-shape-with-css-or-svg/29922567#29922567

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use ::after on the logo. Then arrange that with rotate and positioning, along with a red border. Will also be easy to 'display none' it once you get to responsive... Should do the trick. Of course, this is dependent on your needed browser support